# How to send exception caught in gRPC C# server Error Interceptor to TypeScript gRPC-Web client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, .net-core, grpc

I need to sent custom exceptions message to client.
I have the following code:

- in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddGrpc(options => options.Interceptors.Add<ErrorInterceptor>());
```

- in ErrorInterceptor.cs

```
public override async Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ServerCallContext context, UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
{
    try
    {
        return await continuation(request, context);
    }
    catch (ValidationException validationExc)
    {
        await WriteResponseHeadersAsync(StatusCode.InvalidArgument, translation =>
             translation.GetEnumTranslation(validationExc.Error, validationExc.Parameters));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await WriteResponseHeadersAsync(StatusCode.Internal, translation =>
             translation.GetEnumTranslation(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));
    }
    return default;

    Task WriteResponseHeadersAsync(StatusCode statusCode, Func<ITranslationService, string> getMessage)
    {
        var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
        var translationService = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ITranslationService>();
        var errorMessage = getMessage(translationService);
        var responseHeaders = new Metadata
        {
            { nameof(errorMessage) , errorMessage },//1) can see in browser's devTools, but not in the code
            { "content-type" , errorMessage },//2) ugly, but works
        };
        context.Status = new Status(statusCode, errorMessage);//3) not working
        return context.WriteResponseHeadersAsync(responseHeaders);//4) alternative?
    }
}
```

- in mask-http.service.ts

```
    this.grpcClient.add(request, (error, reply: MaskInfoReply) => {
        this.grpcBaseService.handleResponse<MaskInfoReply.AsObject>(error, reply, response => {
            const mask = new Mask(response.id, response.name);
            callback(mask);
        });
    });
```

- in grpc-base.service.ts

```
    handleResponse<T>(error: ServiceError,
        reply: {
            toObject(includeInstance?: boolean): T;
        },
        func: (response: T) => void) {

        if (error) {
            const errorMessage = error.metadata.headersMap['content-type'][0];
            this.toasterService.openSnackBar(errorMessage, "Ok");
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }
        const response = reply.toObject();
        func(response);
    }
```

1. I wanted to send error using Status (comment 3), but it doesn't get changed
2. I wonder if there is an alternative way to send it not in response headers (comment 4)
3. I tried to add custom response header (comment 1), but the only one I received in client code was 'content-type' so I decided to overwrite it (comment 2)

Comment: HI Did you find out, Im in the same scenario where I need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same dead end recently and decided to do it this way:

1. Create an error model:

   ```
   message ValidationErrorDto {
       // A path leading to a field in the request body.
       string field = 1;

       // A description of why the request element is bad.
       string description = 2;
   }

   message ErrorSynopsisDto {
     string traceTag = 1;
     repeated ValidationErrorDto validationErrors = 2;
   }
   ```
2. Create an extension for the error model that serializes the object to JSON:

   ```
   using Newtonsoft.Json;
   using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

   public static class ErrorSynopsisDtoExtension
   {
       public static string ToJson(this ErrorSynopsisDto errorSynopsisDto) =>
       JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
           errorSynopsisDto,
           new JsonSerializerSettings
           {
               ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
           });
   }
   ```
3. Create a custom exception that encapsulates error model:

   ```
   public class OperationException : Exception
   {
       private readonly List<ValidationErrorDto> validationErrors = new();
       public bool HasValidationErrors => this.validationErrors.Count > 0;

       public OperationException(string traceTag) : base
           (
               new ErrorSynopsisDto
               {
                   TraceTag = traceTag
               }.ToJson() // <- here goes that extension
           ) => ErrorTag = traceTag;

       public OperationException(
           string traceTag,
           List<ValidationErrorDto> validationErrors
       ) : base
           (
               new ErrorSynopsisDto
               {
                   TraceTag = traceTag,
                   ValidationErrors = { validationErrors }
               }.ToJson() // <- here goes that extension again
           )
       {
           ErrorTag = traceTag;
           this.validationErrors = validationErrors;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Throw custom exception from service call handlers:

   ```
   throw new OperationException(
       "MY_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_ERROR_CODE",
       // the following block can be simplified with a mapper, for reduced boilerplate
       new()
       {
           new()
           {
               Field = "Profile.FirstName",
               Description = "Is Required."
           }
       }
   );
   ```
5. And lastly, the exception interceptor:

   ```
   public class ExceptionInterceptor : Interceptor
   {
       private readonly ILogger<ExceptionInterceptor> logger;

       public ExceptionInterceptor(ILogger<ExceptionInterceptor> logger) => this.logger = logger;

       public override async Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(
           TRequest request,
           ServerCallContext context,
           UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation
       )
       {
           try
           {
               return await continuation(request, context);
           }
           catch (OperationException ex)
           {
               this.logger.LogError(ex, context.Method);
               var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();

               if (ex.HasValidationErrors)
               {
                   httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
               }
               else
               {
                   httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
               }

               throw;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               this.logger.LogError(ex, context.Method);
               var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
               httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
               var opEx = new OperationException("MY_CUSTOM_INTERNAL_ERROR_CODE");

               throw new RpcException(
                   new Status(
                       StatusCode.Internal,
                       opEx.Message
                   )
               );

           }
       }
   }
   ```

On the TypeScript-based frontend, I simply catch RPC errors and hydrate the *message* like this:

```
JSON.parse(err.message ?? {}) as ErrorSynopsisDto
```